# Oracle SQL Count with join

Tags: sql, oracle, join, count, sap-erp

I am trying to count Orders and Order lines dependent upon order type. So far I have counted the Order headers per order type.

```
SELECT lifnr, 
  COUNT(CASE WHEN e1.bsart = 'NB' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) Schedule_Orders,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN e1.bsart = 'ZNBS' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) Store_Orders, 
  COUNT(CASE WHEN e1.bsart = 'ZCSO' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) Third_Party,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN e1.bsart NOT IN ('ZCSO', 'NB', 'ZNBS' ) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) Other_Orders,
  COUNT(*) Total_Orders
FROM saprpe.ekko e1 
JOIN saprpe.ekpo p1
ON e1.ebeln = p1.ebeln
WHERE e1.aedat BETWEEN '20130701' AND '20140701'
GROUP BY lifnr
```

Order Lines are stored in table EKPO so I have joined EKKO to EKPO using the document number. How do I go about counting order lines for each of the order types on the case above? I've only managed to count ALL order lines, not specifically for each order type.

**Extra Info:** An Order header is stored in EKKO which contains a Vendor, an OrderNumber and an OrderType. EKKO has a 1-to-many relationship with table EKPO which contains Order lines. Order lines relates to Order Header through the Order Number.

What I am trying to do is get the total order headers for the three order types NB, ZNBS and ZCSO, and the total lines for each order type. All into their own columns

For example I would want to see;

Vendor1, 10 NB orders, 100 NB Order Lines, 0 ZNBS Orders, 0 ZNBS Order Lines, 5 ZCSO Orders, 15 ZCSO Order Lines, 15 Total Orders, 115 Total Order Lines

Please point out if I need to clarify anything. I should note I would prefer this in a single SQL query, I can manage it on an individual query basis for each Order Type using the WHERE clause.

Comment: Can you provide sample data and desired results?  I still have no idea what you mean by "How do i go about counting order lines for each of the order types on the case above?"

Comment: Was a nightmare trying to format some sample data in here! I will edit the content to make it more clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trial and error, googling etc, I eventually got there.

```
SELECT 
  lifnr,
  COUNT(DISTINCT (CASE WHEN e1.bsart = 'NB' THEN e1.ebeln ELSE NULL END)) Schedule_Orders,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN e1.bsart = 'NB' THEN e1.ebeln ELSE NULL END) Schedule_Order_Lines,
  COUNT(DISTINCT (CASE WHEN e1.bsart = 'ZNBS' THEN e1.ebeln ELSE NULL END)) Store_Orders,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN e1.bsart = 'ZNBS' THEN e1.ebeln ELSE NULL END) Store_Order_Lines,
  COUNT(DISTINCT (CASE WHEN e1.bsart = 'ZCSO' THEN e1.ebeln ELSE NULL END)) Third_Party,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN e1.bsart = 'ZCSO' THEN e1.ebeln ELSE NULL END) Third_Party_Lines,
  COUNT(DISTINCT (CASE WHEN e1.bsart NOT IN ('ZCSO', 'NB', 'ZNBS' ) THEN e1.ebeln ELSE NULL END)) Other_Orders,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN e1.bsart NOT IN ('ZCSO', 'NB', 'ZNBS') THEN e1.ebeln ELSE NULL END) Other_Order_Lines,
  COUNT(DISTINCT(e1.ebeln)) Total_Orders,
  COUNT(e1.ebeln) Total_Order_Lines
FROM saprpe.ekko e1
LEFT JOIN saprpe.ekpo p1
ON e1.ebeln = p1.ebeln
WHERE e1.aedat BETWEEN '20130701' AND '20140701'
GROUP BY lifnr
```

The JOIN originally was making my header count the same count as the lines because of the relationship between the tables... Adding DISTINCT to my header counts and using a case for the line counts enabled me to count for those order types.

Comment: You may want to look into the "decode" keyword.  It may simplify some of your case - when statements.  You can't always substitute it, but this looks like a nice example of when you can.